# How to disable caching for laravel pennant in db

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel pennant for feature flags, essentially only for reading if the features are enabled or not. Is there a way for pennant to not use the DB and store data in Features table? I want the feature flags to be computed on every request.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `PENNANT_STORE` in your .env file to `array` to use in-memory storage.

```php
PENNANT_STORE=array
```

You may need to run `php artisan optimize` for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable caching for Laravel Eloquent queries, you can do so by turning off query caching using the **disableQueryLog** method. Here's how you can use it:

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
```

Here it's example:

```
public function someControllerMethod()
{
    // Disable query caching for this specific method
    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

    // Your Eloquent queries go here
    $results = YourModel::where('column', 'value')->get();
}
```

By calling **DB::connection()->disableQueryLog()**, you ensure that query caching is disabled for the specific block of code where you need it. This allows you to run queries without caching within that context.